# How to read from one file to another?

Tags: python, function, file, read-write

I have to create two functions in Python, one for reading from a file and another for copying the content of the file to another one. I also have to do the Caesar cypher on the text I copy from the first file, but I haven't gotten to that yet so I just wrote a random operation on the text, here's the code:

```
def read_file(path):
    with open(path, "r") as fd:
        return fd.read()


def create_file(path, text):
    with open(path, "w") as fd:
        return fd.write(text)


def caesar_encrypt(source: str, dest: str, shift: int = 3):
    text = read_file(source)
    text = '_'.join(text.split('0'))
    create_file(dest, text)


caesar_encrypt('wwww', 'w2.txt')
```

it gives me an error in lines 2, 12 and 17, and also on the last line saying that 'wwww' doesn't exist (doesn't it have to create it if it doesn't exist?)

Comment: www is not a valid file (probably doesn't exist). I tested the code with a a text file which existed and added some content to it and it create my w2.txt with the text from the source file

Comment: You're passing `'wwww'` as `source`, which you then pass to `read_file()` as `path`, where you try to open the file with name `path` for reading. No, it does not create a file automatically, if you try to open it for reading, only when you open it for writing.

Comment: No, when you try to open a file in read-only mode ("r" - and its also the default so you don't need it), the file must exist. This is a normal error. What would you like your program to do when somebody asks to encrypt a file that doesn't exist. Add a try/except and do that.